# Why Special character password is not recognized in libgit2?

Tags: libgit2

Our company's password rules are very strict and require special characters. When I use '§' as the password, I can't always upload the data, but tortoisegit can upload normally. Does libgit2 not support this type of character data?

```
int cred_acquire_cb(git_cred **cred, const char *url, const char *username_from_url, unsigned int allowed_types, void *playload)
{
   return gitt_cred_userpass_plaintext_new(cred, "fuxxxx", "§§abcxxx");// '§' is not recognized.
}
git_push_options options;
options.callbacks.credentials = cred_acquire_cb;
int error = git_push(remote, NULL, &options); //return credentials error.
```

Comment: Are you literally hard-coding the password in your source file? If so, what is the character encoding of your source file? Your server probably expects username and password to be encoded in UTF-8. In that case you would need to ensure that your source file is also UTF-8.

Comment: @JasonHaslam Thanks, I am try to hard-coding and uTF-8 or ASCII
All attempts are still invalid, so I suspect that libgit2 does not support ‘§’ special character.

Comment: `libgit2` simply prints the username and password unaltered into an HTTP authorization header. If you're using gcc, you may want to look at the `-finput-charset` option in case your default locale does not specify UTF-8. In any case, I would advise setting a breakpoint in `git_cred_userpass_plaintext_new` and inspecting the password to see if it is being represented as UTF-8.